# How to make multiple working on this case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Javascript

```
$(".show").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {    
        $(".text_area").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".text_area").hide();
    }
});
```

I want to use this code for all element with this class but, when i select option with "value 1" that make effect to all elements. Please help. Thank you.
Here is demo Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n1fjo6qu/11/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you happen to change the order of the html, for example place text area before the select box, it would not work. So as an alternative for the previous answer, you can wrap your groups into a div:

```
<div class="container">
    <select class="show">
        <option value="0">NO</option>
        <option value="1">YES</option>
    </select>
    <textarea class="form-control text_area" type="text" name="text_area" placeholder="Write something" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
```

and when you are going to display/hide the text areas, you can do:

```
$(this).closest('.container').find('.text_area').show();
```

or

```
$(this).closest('.container').find('.text_area').hide();
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n1fjo6qu/13/

Comment: @balnazzar, if this worked out for you, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

use `$(this).next()`:

```
$(".show").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
        $(this).next(".text_area").show();
    } else {
        $(this).next(".text_area").hide();
    }
});
```

---

You have to make use of keyword `this`. `$(this)` works within the event of context of your selector.

As you have class name as a selector, so you should note that it returns a collection. It means if you have more than one element then it will refer to all and `this` refers to the event applied on the current selector in the collection.